# PHP - Access shared Memory created with C++

Tags: php, c++, ipc, shared-memory

Since a few days i'm trying to get the following thing to work:
I have a tiny C++ program which reads some data continuously from a serial port.
This data is stored in shared memory like this:

```
HANDLE hMapFile;
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE,
    0,
    10,
    NULL);

LPCTSTR pBuf;
pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFileEx(
    hMapFile,
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    0,
    10,
    NULL);

while(true)
{
    //... some code ...
    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    //... some code ...
}
```

Now i would like to access this shared memory with PHP. so i tried to do the following:

```
$shm_id = shmop_open($key, $mode, $security, $size);
$read = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 10);
//... some code ...
```

But i don't know which key, mode, security and size i should set!

Now, before you gonna write something:
I use "MapViewOfFileEx()" because i would like to set a fixed address so PHP can read from a fixed address.
I also tried this with "0x00030000" both in C++ and PHP. C++ was able to create the FileMapping, but PHP can't access giving the error-message: shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment.
As $mode i set "a" for only read-permissions.
As $security i set 0777 for all-access...
As $size i set 10 byte.

As written in the PHP-manual they say i should set 0 for $security AND $size, if i'm trying to attach to a existing shared-memory, but this is also not working.

How can i get this concept done? I guess that the BaseAdress of C++ is not the same like the $key in PHP, but
how can i tell PHP then where the shared-memory block is?
If this is impossible to get this working: Would there be another way to transmit data from a C++ program to PHP (running on wamp-server)?

PS: as i recently read in other questions, it seems to be impossible to communicate with shared-memory... I never worked with named-pipes before, but how would my problem be realized using named-pipes? Or is there a better/faster way to enable communication between C++ and PHP?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to use cpp program only (?) for reading from serial port?

Comment: I can't help in regards of shared memory but you might want to look into writing a PHP extension if you absolutely need communication between your C++ code and PHP.

Comment: @mlask there is no particular reason but i've worked with shared-memory with C++ before. I also looked for possibilities reading serial port data with PHP, but I also need other functionalities of C++ and I guess that continuously reading data from serial port with PHP is very CPU-intensive. EDIT: i'm going to do a AJAX-Request every second and i'm afraid PHP would be too slow to get and open the port, read data, processing it and then closing port again...

Comment: @Mahn uff! This would be very interesting to write my own PHP-extension, but i have no plan how to do this! Do you have any hints where to inform about this? :-)

Comment: @SaschaP sorry, can't help there either, not an extension developer, I just know it's technically possible.

Comment: Nope, it isn't. You can use, for example, `dio` extension for direct IO access to serial port. We created a lot of command line and daemon solutions in PHP and some of them are communicating in real time with GSM modems - everything works perfectly and without eating much resources.

Comment: @Mahn thank you anyway for this clue, i never thought about this before!

Comment: @mlask oh, that's fine! I already tried to get dio-extension to work! so i'll give it another try and also will implement all other things i had implemented to C++ before... I'll write back here when i had time to do this all!

Comment: I had to do something like this, and to avoid all of the issues already mentioned here, I gave up and just wrote a third app to read the shared memory into a SQL database for PHP to access as often and as frequently as it needed. This is not advised, this is not best practice, your coworkers will point and laugh at you and call you silly names, and it will never pass a code review, but at the end of the day it does work.

Comment: @Mark Haha! Thanks for this advice! I also thought about accessing a MySQL-database (because it is included in wamp-server). I hope the traffic may not overcharge my local-server, but i guess this must be ok with modern hardware! In the moment i can't test any solution, because someone else has got the pc, but as i have a working solution i will post it here as an answer, so anybody can read it! Thank you however!

Comment: as i found out mysql-connector as well as redis require boost-library. So on the one hand there is PHP with dio-functionalities, on the other hand there is boost-library => sending data either to MySQL or to Redis!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use Redis to deal with the communications between C++ and PHP. 
You can use his Pub /sub module, is very powerfull. http://redis.io/topics/pubsub.
Here you have a list of clients for redis: http://redis.io/clients

Comment: this looks very nice! But as i read there i would need boost to use the C++ Redis-Clients... Maybe I'll give it a try! Thank you