# is it possible to share memory between PHP and C in Windows?

Tags: php, c, windows, ipc, shared-memory

Can you use shared memory between a PHP script and a C/C++ program in Windows?
For instance, by using PHP shared memory ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php)) and windows memory mapped files?

Comment: It would be very useful for everyone if you could elaborate more and give some supporting quotes and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it may be possible if you create your own PHP extension. As far as I know, PHP extensions are written in C language.

Probably, there are already some extensions written to do this thing.

UPD:

It looks like it is possible. Please, take a look at this chapter in official docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php. And here is some example: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/memory/shared-memory-between-c-application-and-php-web-server

UPD 2:

I'm not very familiar with shared memory  and memory mapped files, but it looks like these questions are somehow similar to yours: [Shared memory C++ - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997082/shared-memory-c-php) and [PHP - Access shared Memory created with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058427/php-access-shared-memory-created-with-c).

Also, you might be interested to read a book "Advanced PHP Programming" by George Schlossnagle ([link](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=mCpnlNYzqOQC&pg=PA571&lpg=PA571&dq=memory+mapped+files+in+php+%2Bphp+-.net+-java&source=bl&ots=qAUTgzmpV4&sig=RzogltErtJJAhfbP7MTItaFB09w&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=gSBXVdKxFcGyswG21YGYAw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=memory%20mapped%20files%20in%20php%20%2Bphp%20-.net%20-java&f=false)). It looks like there is an example of how to implement a PHP extension to work with memory-mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Starting from the links above I have been able to write a PHP extesion and a simple program which share the same Named Shared Memory.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/#Heading12